# WinBUGS "Array index is greater than array upper bound for a"

Tags: winbugs

I have a simple Bayesian hierachical model (linear mixed model with random intercepts) which should be easy to run. The problem is that after successfully loading the model and data, I get the following error when I try to compile the model, "array index is greater than array upper bound for a." It seems like this should be an easy fix, but I've repeatedly checked the indexing, and the data, and cannot find a problem. I have experimented on different example datasets, and don't have any issue, which makes me think something other then indexing is the problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
model{
  for (i in 1:n) {                      
    y[i] ~ dnorm(y.hat[i],tau.y) 
    y.hat[i]<- a[d[i]] + beta0 + beta1*x[i]  
  }
  beta0 ~ dnorm(50, 0.001) I(0, )   
  beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  tau.y <- pow(sigma.y,-2)
  sigma.y ~ dunif(0,100)
  for (j in 1:J){
    a[j] ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
    a.hat[j] <- mu.a
  }
  mu.a ~ dnorm(0, .0001)   
  tau.a <- pow(sigma.a, -2)   
  sigma.a ~ dunif(0, 100)
}

list( n = 904, J = 44, y = c( 61.46, 86, 75.11, 77.31, 65.7, 71.82, 61.42, 63.8, 45.53, 48.29, 
43.77, 51.6, 80.1, 51.1, 65.9, 71.9, 66.73, 68.96, 86, 74.3, 72.9, 66.9, 54.4, 
66, 70, 64, 78.6, 70.6, 80.2, 75.2, 63.6, 62.7, 71.9, 56.1, 59.6, 57.6, 61, 
59.9, 57.2, 51.4, 62.8, 70, 60.7, 63.3, 60.4, 65.3, 75.45, 63.8, 68.21, 70.45, 
59.28, 53.05, 43.6, 30.82, 79.74, 56.03, 66.88, 49.31, 64.17, 56.57, 54.37, 
51.99, 49.56, 42.6, 48.52, 51.72, 59.43, 57.81, 57.29, 57.79, 67.14, 70, 61.38, 
54.23, 63.41, 58.19, 67.23, 31.91, 40.95, 53.83, 49.84, 53.32, 61.2, 52.11, 
53.83, 58.13, 54.21, 52.72, 49.12, 43.7, 50.2, 36.93, 59.7, 57.8, 50.7, 68.2, 
47.2, 70.27, 90.75, 72.16, 75.05, 75.2, 56.58, 63.59, 43.53, 35.6, 49.19, 
64.36, 45.77, 53.85, 30.92, 56.99, 85.54, 77.73, 65, 42.11, 47.47, 25.3, 34.82, 
21.5, 72.76, 81.08, 77.18, 69.41, 58.54, 72.73, 59.45, 63, 63.9, 62.15, 55.58, 
49.72, 47.11, 54.85, 47.63, 47.7, 49.75, 48.32, 59.15, 77.3, 73.7, 87.73, 55, 
61.3, 52.2, 52.9, 48.3, 58.7, 53.48, 78.88, 77.43, 81.94, 73.24, 71.75, 64.99, 
66.99, 63.82, 57.23, 54.15, 57.08, 54.35, 65.24, 78.26, 63.63, 68.72, 65.21, 
71.4, 44.54, 57.89, 60.9, 51.3, 64.84, 54, 52.76, 91.03, 93.05, 75.1, 71.89, 
77.68, 79.88, 74.01, 56.67, 59.06, 48.66, 67.09, 41.25, 61.18, 68.31, 46.74, 
50.87, 72.13, 79.7, 77.18, 58.28, 44.42, 60.12, 66.9, 67.73, 77.59, 62.12, 
63.01, 84.65, 100, 69.56, 62.48, 47.2, 72.83, 52.83, 68.04, 69.11, 63.91, 
56.25, 57.43, 86.5, 65.44, 70, 69, 65, 68, 67, 54, 50, 46, 55, 42, 45, 49.7, 
48.7, 40.1, 51.8, 51.9, 62.5, 50.04, 63.2, 53.8, 57.46, 35.5, 69.94, 87.04, 
82.1, 73.44, 67.49, 76.53, 73.21, 59.37, 63.41, 63.54, 59.56, 58.93, 56.38, 
51.99, 50.94, 53.63, 57.79, 50.8, 53.66, 50.12, 47.58, 51.46, 56.57, 60.64, 
63.23, 60.7, 61.2, 64.03, 68.85, 77.96, 74.98, 56.38, 83.7, 62.29, 68.38, 
40.18, 71.12, 37.69, 68.43, 53.69, 76.56, 71.15, 67.67, 45.75, 75.21, 48.96, 
53, 52.7, 34.6, 60.09, 52.18, 65.92, 71, 60.95, 61.79, 57.6, 52.91, 59.26, 
48.98, 60.66, 42.7, 52.8, 41.14, 56.52, 42.54, 36.26, 35.68, 74.61, 61.22, 
69.58, 63.14, 58.76, 56.82, 46.7, 54.82, 48.04, 56.47, 60.6, 53.11, 67, 51.88, 
45.41, 46.76, 83.91, 55.55, 22.41, 38.54, 44.98, 41.47, 39.44, 54.04, 55.9, 
67.3, 56.4, 68, 67.7, 62.8, 46.1, 86.44, 55.7, 61.98, 66.12, 77.48, 65.55, 
62.58, 77.43, 99.05, 57.97, 49.57, 60.8, 52.68, 77.39, 63.34, 66.21, 67.25, 
83.61, 64.02, 63.07, 58.1, 57.29, 55.68, 41, 45.65, 49.31, 55.91, 56.47, 58.5, 
68.64, 61.64, 78.46, 72.22, 40.86, 50.36, 47.65, 50.06, 64, 63.35, 61.06, 
47.24, 39.05, 45.22, 40.13, 33.94, 31.59, 34.2, 52.5, 38.46, 50.89, 63.63, 
43.12, 56.92, 53.04, 63.26, 61.13, 63.7, 44.6, 45.37, 55.28, 84.3, 66.2, 64, 
84, 47.8, 36, 36.9, 37.6, 50.3, 55.9, 42.9, 47, 43.8, 29.7, 42.8, 36.2, 35.3, 
33.8, 38.2, 35.9, 37.1, 30.6, 44.6, 49.3, 34.9, 37, 37.6, 26.7, 40.8, 40.45, 
53.8, 45.12, 29.48, 47.19, 66.23, 63.68, 63.91, 55.36, 55.96, 44.9, 36.8, 
46.47, 47.76, 40.35, 41.97, 42, 60, 47.2, 49.72, 34.69, 43.14, 51.18, 52.81, 
51.02, 45.89, 46.9, 28.6, 44.48, 41.31, 66.09, 56.26, 47.43, 31.9, 54.59, 
61.56, 67.03, 69.74, 61.55, 63.02, 50.9, 52.9, 50.68, 48.36, 41.53, 35.13, 50, 
49.21, 59.69, 39.45, 56.26, 48.78, 50.65, 45.26, 47.19, 50, 30.2, 46.81, 56.3, 
48.24, 37.56, 57.35, 50.4, 42.39, 44.31, 45.43, 61.9, 55.03, 55.19, 52.83, 
46.51, 45.66, 55.14, 58.89, 56.74, 46.58, 62.51, 45.15, 51.56, 44.95, 48.11, 
44.33, 58.3, 49.5, 54.3, 46.5, 53.9, 37.7, 43.51, 39.86, 58.43, 68.21, 54.07, 
55.67, 71.11, 67.25, 72.5, 63.41, 51.36, 51.74, 53.44, 55.8, 58.79, 44.12, 
31.4, 46.9, 43.6, 46.18, 36.24, 41.08, 47.85, 53.69, 37.53, 37.43, 40.3, 21.3, 
42.49, 55.71, 62.2, 58.45, 63.45, 58.13, 53.59, 57.82, 55.94, 53.44, 50.86, 
20.85, 27.08, 42.8, 34.29, 38.9, 34.59, 26.45, 72.34, 104.88, 73.93, 66.95, 
75.72, 75.1, 53.9, 74.67, 73.97, 85.5, 85.38, 59.7, 59.36, 44.51, 62.25, 56.26, 
62.77, 60.24, 55.13, 61.35, 66.21, 56.06, 60.46, 70.45, 50, 66.44, 48.24, 
55.56, 71.13, 60.97, 37.94, 43.6, 36, 51.22, 57.84, 58.56, 57.14, 63.51, 50.35, 
58.68, 62.46, 59.02, 62.23, 59.44, 66.82, 65.38, 53.92, 57.73, 43.34, 58.41, 
65.06, 56.91, 49.01, 53.5, 48.6, 52.47, 46.04, 58.81, 39.29, 43.59, 77.4, 30.9, 
50.5, 31.66, 125, 37.8, 53.91, 59.84, 50, 52.31, 39.53, 47.87, 39.58, 46.97, 
56.16, 57.78, 44.52, 40.22, 52.56, 45.45, 47.17, 76, 91.95, 78.97, 64.81, 
55.56, 53.1, 51.71, 55.9, 93.6, 74.62, 53.37, 57.1, 62.57, 40.58, 56.75, 61.58, 
58.08, 61.59, 65.45, 64.1, 57.03, 56.5, 49.56, 50, 32.84, 21.69, 51.9, 28.59, 
45.2, 28.17, 39.29, 68.6, 57.07, 61.11, 48.05, 56.43, 63.2, 71.71, 55.25, 
50.18, 43.23, 41.67, 30.37, 37.5, 38.39, 32.8, 37.36, 39.39, 54.41, 64.94, 
60.38, 52.36, 53.57, 59.87, 70.77, 56.8, 55.1, 47.46, 48.98, 61.2, 30.41, 38.4, 
43.19, 76.56, 74.65, 57.64, 60.87, 81.58, 83.3, 63.41, 54.05, 51.48, 54.01, 
48.4, 52.24, 49.9, 43.4, 47.17, 43.6, 36.6, 40, 36.46, 38.56, 47.99, 49.58, 
54.2, 42.51, 41.6, 33.2, 43.95, 41.31, 86.05, 66.98, 53.75, 58.36, 45.73, 
53.42, 55.88, 69.72, 73.8, 67.85, 54.74, 52.36, 61, 56.58, 40.82, 40.77, 42.42, 
38.44, 52.79, 52.73, 35.2, 46.03, 62.01, 64.46, 56.4, 36, 46.79, 48.64, 66.67, 
72.03, 65.42, 82.25, 74.69, 62.61, 61.21, 53.09, 56.19, 57.95, 57.21, 43.76, 
66.5, 55.76, 57.69, 59.67, 74.96, 58.78, 67.3, 69.15, 68.33, 71.56, 75.29, 
67.05, 68.86, 78.61, 59.19, 51.66, 56.31, 64.66, 47.29, 58.39, 60.22, 40, 41.4, 
41.38, 46.76, 61.8, 61.4, 68.63, 87.7, 78.46, 70.51, 59.77, 65.42, 72.1, 59.38, 
61.21, 46.28, 41.42, 54.18, 47.31, 45.51, 36.31, 51.03, 61.08, 25.08, 59.45, 
58.81, 60.37, 50, 80, 61.5, 89.44, 88.1, 75, 61.9, 80.56, 42.86, 67.31, 85.71, 
60, 59.4, 43.99, 64.52, 69.4, 55.14, 43.75, 75, 76.71, 52.93, 52.34, 45.21, 
38.28, 50.91, 61.54, 61.11, 45.87, 47.6, 45.05, 44.43, 52.9, 34.52, 40.57, 
40.5, 37.3, 38, 45.06, 33.71, 32.12, 48.4, 39.78, 39.86, 36.8, 31.8, 47.86, 
41.78, 48, 60, 49.8, 55.2, 44.6, 60.4, 57.4, 65.9, 59.1, 52.2, 54.41, 62.32, 
57.33, 68.17, 62.96, 50.33, 51.48, 48.73, 59.56, 61.96, 56.68, 32, 49.6, 45.8, 
53.16, 39.58, 58.55, 54.7, 42.53, 39.59, 33.33, 69.67, 66.79, 44.14, 47.75, 
65.38, 39.7, 76.97, 34) , d = c( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
43, 43, 43, 43, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53) , x = c( 0.54, 0.5350262, 0.554, 0.582, 0.624, 
0.638, 0.652, 0.666, 0.6834799, 0.681, 0.682, 0.684, 0.685, 0.686, 0.687, 
0.688, 0.689, 0.6918783, 10.13947, 10.252, 10.364, 10.476, 10.588, 10.7, 
10.812, 10.924, 11.036, 11.148, 11.25654, 11.757, 12.254, 12.751, 13.248, 
13.745, 14.242, 14.739, 15.236, 15.733, 16.22779, 16.232, 16.234, 16.236, 
16.238, 16.24, 16.242, 16.244, 16.246, 16.248, 16.24809, 10.28, 10.28, 10.28, 
10.28, 10.28, 10.28, 10.28, 10.28, 10.498, 10.716, 10.934, 11.152, 11.37, 
11.588, 11.806, 12.242, 12.45755, 12.464, 12.466, 12.468, 12.472, 12.474, 
12.476, 12.478, 12.48307, 20.445, 20.495, 20.57, 20.62, 20.67224, 21.01, 21.35, 
21.69, 22.03, 22.37, 22.71, 23.05, 23.39, 23.73, 24.06687, 24.098, 24.126, 
24.154, 24.182, 24.21, 24.266, 24.322, 24.34951, 2.517, 2.614, 2.711, 3.002, 
3.099, 3.293, 3.386308, 3.584, 3.778, 3.972, 4.166, 4.748, 4.942, 5.329492, 
5.34, 5.345, 5.35, 5.355, 5.36, 5.365, 5.37, 5.375, 5.384694, 8.443984, 8.604, 
8.768, 8.932, 9.096, 9.26, 9.424, 9.752, 9.916, 10.07591, 10.391, 10.702, 
11.013, 11.324, 11.635, 12.257, 12.568, 12.879, 13.19029, 13.211, 13.232, 
13.253, 13.274, 13.295, 13.316, 13.337, 13.358, 13.379, 13.3975, 10.23494, 
10.26, 10.29, 10.32, 10.35, 10.41, 10.47, 10.52766, 11.038, 11.546, 12.054, 
12.308, 12.816, 13.06939, 13.582, 14.094, 14.606, 15.118, 15.63, 16.142, 
16.654, 17.166, 17.678, 18.19218, 10.25687, 10.412, 10.716, 10.868, 11.172, 
11.324, 11.628, 11.945, 12.11, 12.44, 12.605, 12.77, 12.935, 13.1, 13.265, 
13.4293, 13.499, 13.568, 13.637, 13.706, 13.775, 13.844, 13.913, 13.982, 
14.051, 14.12134, 31.87835, 31.952, 32.024, 32.06, 32.096, 32.23761, 32.322, 
32.527, 32.609, 32.821, 32.992, 33.163, 33.505, 33.676, 34.018, 34.189, 8.564, 
8.568, 8.572, 8.58, 8.588, 8.596, 8.596099, 8.625, 8.675, 8.7, 8.725, 8.775, 
8.8, 8.825, 8.96, 9.29, 9.4, 9.51, 9.62, 9.73, 9.84, 9.950349, 21.62867, 21.88, 
22.13, 22.38, 22.63, 22.88, 23.13, 23.38, 23.63, 23.88, 24.12896, 24.482, 
24.834, 25.186, 25.538, 25.89, 26.242, 26.594, 27.298, 27.6469, 28.052, 28.253, 
28.454, 28.655, 28.856, 29.057, 29.258, 29.459, 29.65551, 16.064, 16.092, 
16.12, 16.148, 16.176, 16.206, 16.238, 16.286, 16.302, 16.318, 16.334, 
16.34918, 16.382, 16.414, 16.446, 16.478, 16.51, 16.542, 16.574, 16.606, 
16.638, 16.66627, 15.708, 15.864, 16.098, 16.254, 16.40707, 16.424, 16.438, 
16.452, 16.466, 16.48, 16.494, 16.508, 16.522, 16.536, 16.55052, 16.816, 
17.082, 17.348, 17.614, 17.88, 18.146, 18.412, 18.678, 18.944, 19.20852, 
17.284, 17.328, 17.372, 17.416, 17.45741, 23.314, 23.572, 24.088, 28.775, 
30.237, 31.699, 32.43322, 32.979, 33.528, 34.077, 34.626, 35.175, 35.724, 
36.273, 36.822, 37.371, 37.92301, 36.728, 36.977, 37.314, 37.441, 37.695, 
38.076, 38.3302, 38.686, 38.864, 39.22, 39.576, 39.932, 13.29665, 13.53, 13.76, 
13.99, 14.22, 14.68, 15.14, 15.59616, 16.44, 17.28, 18.12, 19.79912, 19.922, 
20.044, 20.105, 20.166, 20.288, 20.349, 20.41163, 13.208, 13.252, 13.296, 
13.34, 13.384, 13.428, 13.472, 13.516, 13.56361, 13.746, 13.932, 14.118, 
14.304, 14.49, 14.676, 14.862, 15.048, 15.234, 15.42321, 15.54, 15.66, 15.78, 
15.9, 16.02, 16.14, 16.26, 16.38, 16.5, 16.6215, 17.40591, 17.485, 17.56, 
17.635, 17.71, 17.785, 17.86, 17.935, 18.01, 18.085, 18.16367, 18.167, 18.174, 
18.181, 18.188, 18.195, 18.202, 18.209, 18.216, 18.223, 18.2299, 18.23, 18.23, 
18.23, 18.23, 18.23, 18.23, 18.23, 18.23, 18.2299, 9.266, 9.738, 9.974, 10.21, 
10.446, 10.682, 10.918, 11.154, 11.38546, 11.586, 11.782, 11.978, 12.174, 
12.37, 12.566, 12.762, 12.958, 13.154, 13.355, 13.365, 13.38, 13.395, 13.41, 
13.425, 13.44, 13.455, 13.47, 13.485, 13.49869, 7.424, 7.472, 7.496, 7.52, 
7.544, 7.568, 7.592, 7.616, 7.641526, 7.678, 7.716, 7.754, 7.792, 7.83, 7.868, 
7.906, 7.944, 7.982, 8.02042, 8.085, 8.15, 8.215, 8.28, 8.345, 8.41, 8.475, 
8.54, 8.605, 8.666293, 7.663, 8.116, 11.196, 11.249, 11.302, 11.355, 11.408, 
11.461, 11.514, 11.567, 11.61951, 12.205, 12.79, 13.375, 13.96, 14.545, 15.13, 
15.715, 16.3, 16.885, 17.46967, 17.484, 17.498, 17.512, 17.526, 17.54, 17.554, 
17.568, 17.582, 17.596, 17.61099, 4.495, 4.745, 4.995, 5.12, 5.245, 5.37, 
5.495, 5.624713, 5.658, 5.696, 5.734, 5.772, 5.81, 5.848, 5.886, 5.924, 5.962, 
6.004034, 6.305, 6.61, 6.915, 7.22, 7.525, 7.83, 8.135, 8.44, 8.745, 9.054572, 
10.14, 10.43, 10.71782, 11.13, 11.335, 11.54, 11.745, 11.95, 12.77435, 14.808, 
16.846, 18.884, 19.903, 20.922, 21.941, 22.95846, 37.338, 37.401, 37.527, 
37.814, 38.038, 38.598, 39.258, 39.532, 40.354, 40.902, 41.44835, 23.081, 
23.294, 23.507, 23.71729, 24.077, 24.434, 24.791, 25.148, 25.505, 25.862, 
26.219, 26.576, 26.933, 27.2913, 27.299, 27.308, 27.317, 27.326, 27.335, 
27.344, 27.353, 27.362, 27.371, 27.38188, 23.306, 23.788, 24.27268, 24.57, 
25.17, 25.47, 25.77, 26.07, 26.37, 26.67, 26.97, 27.2698, 27.577, 27.884, 
28.191, 28.498, 28.805, 29.112, 29.419, 29.726, 30.033, 30.34219, 16.134, 
24.71, 24.71, 24.71, 24.71, 24.71, 24.71, 31.94, 32.16, 32.38, 32.6, 32.82, 
33.26, 33.48, 33.70422, 34.137, 34.574, 35.011, 35.448, 36.322, 37.196, 37.633, 
38.07169, 38.072, 38.076, 38.078, 38.08, 38.082, 38.084, 38.086, 38.088, 
38.08755, 46.095, 46.406, 46.717, 47.028, 47.339, 47.65467, 23.06, 23.1, 
23.14316, 23.622, 23.863, 24.104, 24.345, 24.586, 25.54903, 25.694, 25.838, 
26.27, 26.414, 26.558, 26.702, 26.846, 26.99223, 23.826, 23.863, 23.90286, 
24.322, 24.533, 24.744, 24.955, 25.166, 26.01203, 26.094, 26.178, 26.346, 
26.514, 26.598, 26.682, 26.766, 26.8545, 14.18, 14.365, 14.54838, 15.208, 
15.537, 15.866, 16.195, 16.524, 17.511, 17.84261, 18.423, 21.338, 21.921, 
22.504, 23.66658, 19.814, 23.12309, 24.952, 25.41, 26.326, 27.242, 23.696, 
24.058, 24.42368, 24.597, 24.774, 24.951, 25.128, 25.305, 25.482, 25.659, 
25.836, 26.013, 26.19191, 26.201, 26.212, 26.234, 26.245, 26.256, 26.267, 
26.278, 26.289, 26.30484, 23.55656, 24.102, 24.373, 24.644, 24.915, 25.186, 
25.457, 25.728, 25.999, 26.27382, 26.632, 26.994, 27.356, 27.718, 28.08, 
28.442, 29.166, 29.528, 29.88617, 30.124, 30.358, 30.826, 31.06, 31.294, 
31.528, 31.762, 31.996, 32.22849, 2.742582, 2.774, 2.808, 2.842, 2.876, 2.91, 
2.978, 3.046, 3.144, 3.272, 3.528, 3.656, 3.95, 4.41, 4.64, 4.87, 5.1, 5.33, 
5.56, 5.79, 6.017525, 16.63745, 16.884, 17.128, 17.372, 17.494, 17.738, 
17.86075, 18.016, 18.172, 18.328, 18.484, 18.796, 19.108, 19.42257, 19.64, 
19.86, 20.08, 20.3, 20.52438, 9.794, 9.868, 9.942, 10.016, 10.09, 10.238, 
10.386, 10.597, 10.871, 11.145, 11.282, 11.419, 11.556, 11.693, 11.82756, 
11.97, 12.11, 12.39, 12.53, 12.67, 12.95, 13.09, 13.2299, 23.206, 26.195, 
26.778, 27.944, 28.527, 29.10834, 29.503, 29.896, 30.682, 31.075, 31.468, 
31.861, 32.254, 32.647, 33.04166, 21.83835, 21.946, 21.999, 22.052, 22.105, 
22.158, 22.211, 22.264, 22.317, 22.368, 22.622, 22.874, 23.126, 23.378, 23.63, 
23.882, 24.134, 24.386, 24.638, 24.88723, 24.933, 24.976, 25.062, 25.105, 
25.148, 25.191, 25.234, 25.277, 25.32213, 18.59, 18.81, 19.03, 19.25, 19.47, 
19.68829, 20.517, 21.344, 22.171, 22.998, 23.825, 24.652, 25.479, 26.306, 
27.133, 27.96245, 28.009, 28.058, 28.107, 28.156, 28.205, 28.254, 28.303, 
28.352, 28.401, 28.44787, 18.224, 18.652, 18.866, 19.08125, 19.785, 20.49, 
21.9, 22.605, 23.31, 24.015, 24.72, 25.425, 26.13229) )
```

Comment: You might want to supply `d` as `as.numeric(as.factor(d))`.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs as in `y.hat[i] <-` you allow `a` to take values from `d` (anything from 1,..,53 given in the data) which can be greater than the your upper bound for `a` (`J = 44` given in the data).